# Battery current measurement with shunt resistor

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, voltage-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier, shunt

I want to use a shunt resistor to measure the current that flows from and in a battery. The current is set by power supply for charging(positive current) and by electronic load for discharging (negative current). I want to amplify the voltage drop over the shunt resistor with instrumental op amp that gives a gain equal to 50.4. The op amp that I'm using is [AD620](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf) with Rg resistor equal to 1k with tolerance 0.1%.
I want to send the output of op amp in ADC converter to acquire the measurement.

The problem is that the results aren't what I expected, shown in figure, and I don't understand which is the problem.
In figure there is a comparison with hall-effect sensor(black line), instead the red line is the current measured by shunt.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7cXlv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Results obtained using the reported schematic]

[image: Results obtained connecting one of shunt terminal to ground]

The second figure shows results obtained connecting one of shunt terminal to ground

Comment: You need to tie the bottom end of the shunt to your ground on the AD620, or the inputs are not referenced.

Comment: @Trevor Do I have to  it using a resistor ?

Comment: You can but it will be more noise sensitive.

Comment: Can I connect it directly to ground without resistor?

Comment: Assuming that battery circuit does not connect elsewhere to your system at some other level, yes.

Comment: yes, the battery circuit and the measurement circuit are totally decoupled

Comment: OK then, you must connect the grounds together. This chip cannot implement an isolated measurement (if you need isolation, consider hall sensors instead).

Comment: If you want it truly differential you may want to add two 1mR resistors in series and tie the centre point to ground on the right.

Comment: @Trevor, sorry I don't understand your last answer

Comment: @peufeu You mean to connect ground of measurement circuit with ground of battery circuit?

Comment: Yeah, connect both grounds together. Simplest option.

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: BTW, you can not expect the HALL and R sense to give you exactly the same values.

Comment: and your offset seems awfully high. I'm assuming those curves are from a simulation. Check your model parameters.

Comment: @Trevor those curves come from real measurament...note that the power supply and electronic load are supplied by grid

Answer (score 1):

Would be better with Balanced sensing as shown here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8pXF8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>